# Unable to receive interaction events by specific definition id

Tags: xconnect

I'm unable to receive interaction events by the specific definition id

```
    using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var events = new List<VotePoll>();

            // VotePoll.VotePollId is "{5D824DC3-52A8-4FBD-A6F4-4782E98C44EA}"
            IAsyncQueryable<Interaction> queryable = client.Interactions
                .Where(x => x.Events.Any(y => y.DefinitionId == VotePoll.VotePollId));

            var enumerable = queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(20);

            while (enumerable.MoveNext())
            {
                var interactionBatchPageEvent = enumerable.Current;

                foreach (var interaction in interactionBatchPageEvent)
                {
                    var matchingEvents = interaction.Events.OfType<VotePoll>()
                        .Where(x => x.DefinitionId == VotePoll.VotePollId).ToList();

                    events.AddRange(matchingEvents);
                }
            }

            return events;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Even though I see that these events were successfully registered
[image]
Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve the issue?

Here is some more information:
The VotePoll event

```
public class VotePoll : Sitecore.XConnect.Event
{
    public VotePoll(DateTime timestamp)
        : base(VotePollId, timestamp)
    {
    }

    public static Guid VotePollId = Guid.Parse("{5D824DC3-52A8-4FBD-A6F4-4782E98C44EA}");

    public string InteractiveElementId { get; set; }

    public string InteractiveElementAnswerId { get; set; }

    public Guid VisitorId { get; set; }
}
```

was registered in a custom xDb model

```
private static XdbModel BuildModel()
{
    var builder = new XdbModelBuilder("InteractiveElementTrackingModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));
    builder.ReferenceModel(Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model.CollectionModel.Model);
    builder.DefineFacet<Contact, InteractiveElementTrackingModelFacet>(InteractiveElementTrackingModelFacet.DefaultFacetKey);
    builder.DefineEventType<VotePoll>(false);

    return builder.BuildModel();
}
```

and deployed to xConnect.
The serialized model looks in this way:

```
{
  "Name": "InteractiveElementTrackingModel",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "References": [
    {
      "Name": "XConnect",
      "Version": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model",
      "Version": "9.0"
    }
  ],
  "Types": {
    "XX.Foundation.CustomInteractiveElementTrackingModel.Models.CustomFacets.InteractiveElementTrackingModelFacet": {
      "Type": "Facet",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Facet",
      "ClrType": "XX.Foundation.CustomInteractiveElementTrackingModel.Models.CustomFacets.InteractiveElementTrackingModelFacet, XX.Foundation.CustomInteractiveElementTrackingModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "InteractiveElementId": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "InteractiveElementAnswerId": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "QuestionTitle": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "AnswerTitle": {
          "Type": "String"
        }
      }
    },
    "XX.Foundation.CustomInteractiveElementTrackingModel.Models.CustomEvents.VotePoll": {
      "Type": "Event",
      "BaseType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Event",
      "ClrType": "XX.Foundation.CustomInteractiveElementTrackingModel.Models.CustomEvents.VotePoll, XX.Foundation.CustomInteractiveElementTrackingModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
      "Properties": {
        "InteractiveElementId": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "InteractiveElementAnswerId": {
          "Type": "String"
        },
        "VisitorId": {
          "Type": "Guid"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Facets": [
    {
      "Target": "Contact",
      "Name": "InteractiveElementTrackingModelFacet",
      "Type": "XX.Foundation.CustomInteractiveElementTrackingModel.Models.CustomFacets.InteractiveElementTrackingModelFacet"
    }
  ]
}
```

The event was registered by tracker

```
        var eventData = new Sitecore.Analytics.Data.PageEventData(pageEventDefinition.Alias, pageEventDefinition.Id);

        if (data != null)
        {
            eventData.Data = data;
        }

        if (dataKey != null)
        {
            eventData.DataKey = dataKey;
        }

        if (text != null)
        {
            eventData.Text = text;
        }

        if (customValues != null)
        {
            foreach (var customValue in customValues)
            {
                eventData.CustomValues.Add(customValue);
            }
        }

        Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(eventData);
```

and all the custom properties were transformed in the appropriate pipeline

```
protected override Event CreateEvent(PageEventData pageEventData)
{
    var votePoll = new VotePoll(pageEventData.DateTime)
                       {
                           InteractiveElementId = (string)pageEventData.CustomValues["InteractiveElementId"],
                           InteractiveElementAnswerId =
                               (string)pageEventData.CustomValues["InteractiveElementAnswerId"],
                           VisitorId = (Guid)pageEventData.CustomValues["VisitorId"]
                       };

    return votePoll;
}
```

Also when I query Interactions from Shard databases in SqlServer I receive more than 20 Interactions with properly filled VotePoll events. e.g.:

```
  {
    "@odata.type": "#XX.Foundation.CustomInteractiveElementTrackingModel.Models.CustomEvents.VotePoll",
    "CustomValues": [],
    "Data": "5d824dc3-52a8-4fbd-a6f4-4782e98c44ea",
    "DataKey": "interactiveelementid",
    "DefinitionId": "5d824dc3-52a8-4fbd-a6f4-4782e98c44ea",
    "Id": "efcf3f7b-a899-40e9-9010-21ab7a376bbb",
    "ParentEventId": "56d77129-ba1d-4919-ba64-419c20fecfb6",
    "Text": "Voted by Interactive element",
    "Timestamp": "2019-12-06T13:50:34.4696273Z",
    "InteractiveElementId": "c2a7a5d1-3425-49cd-a1d9-5282cbc79a19",
    "InteractiveElementAnswerId": "e2d77b17-13fc-4fc7-8c0c-26d68fda50fb",
    "VisitorId": "e70535fd-7ee5-4c2a-ac37-fb760009784d"
  }
```

but nothing is returned via xConnect API

Comment: How did you defined `VotePoll` class? Can you please update question with this information?

Comment: @PeterProcházka, I've updated the question with more info. Now it looks much more detailed but less readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was resolved by enabling indexing for anonymous contacts in sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml:

```
  <IndexerSettings>
    <Type>Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexerSettings, Sitecore.Xdb.Collection</Type>
    <LifeTime>Singleton</LifeTime>
    <Options>
        <!-- Indexer will split change set on chunks to improve memory consumption. Setting this option to 0, a negative value or removing the element completely, results in no splitting.-->
      <SplitRecordsThreshold>25000</SplitRecordsThreshold>
      <IndexPIISensitiveData>false</IndexPIISensitiveData>
      <IndexAnonymousContactData>true</IndexAnonymousContactData>
    </Options>
  </IndexerSettings>
```